# Getting started with MongoDB C++ driver in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, mongodb, driver

Trying to set up a simple `MongoDB` database connection in Windows 7, using the `C++ driver`. I'm using `Visual C++ compiler 19` for `x86`, `32-bit MongoDB 3.0.6`, `Boost 1_59_0`, `Mongo legacy 1.0.5 C++ driver`.

Driver compiles OK using the command

```
scons --cpppath=d:\boost_1_59_0 --libpath=d:\boost_1_59_0\stage\lib --msvc-host-arch=x86 install
```

Program is

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include "mongo/client/dbclient.h"

void run() {
  mongo::DBClientConnection c;
  c.connect("localhost");
}

int main() {
  try {
    run();
    std::cout << "connected ok" << std::endl;
  } catch( const mongo::DBException &e ) {
    std::cout << "caught " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Program compiles using

```
cl /EHsc /I"c:\mongo-cxx-driver-legacy-1.0.5\build\install\include" /I"d:\boost_1_59_0" /DSTATIC_LIBMONGOCLIENT mdb.cpp c:\mongo-cxx-driver-legacy-1.0.5\build\install\lib\libmongoclient-s.lib /link /LIBPATH:"D:\boost_1_59_0\stage\lib" ws2_32.lib
```

But when I run the program, get the error message

caught can't connect couldn't initialize connection to `localhost`, address is invalid

The `server` is running OK as I can access it through the `shell`, add records etc.

This is my first time programming `MongoDB` and I'm kind of stuck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

OK, problem solved (thanks to stevepowell.ca/mongo-db-1.html). Here's the answer for anyone else who runs into this problem:

Windows needs to initialize the client before setting up the connection.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <memory>

#include "mongo/client/dbclient.h"

using namespace mongo;
using namespace std;

void run() {
  mongo::client::initialize(); // this line is new
  mongo::DBClientConnection c;
  c.connect("localhost");
}

int main() {
  try {
    run();
    std::cout << "connected ok" << std::endl;
  } catch( const mongo::DBException &e ) {
    std::cout << "caught " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I wish this had been in the tutorial!

Onwards and upwards.

Comment: If you are referring to this tutorial https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Tutorial then it *is* in the tutorial, the first link in the 'Initializing...' section: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Tutorial#initializing-the-driver-library, linking to https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Configuring-the-Legacy-Driver which very clearly identifies the need to initialize the driver.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at the example at https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-cpp-driver.html which does not have the call.

Comment: May I ask what it was that pointed you to those (terrible, mirrored, outdated) docs, rather than the official documentation available at mongodb.org? In particular https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/

Comment: Lack of familiarity with what's available. I'll make a point of going to the official source from now on!